# Angular13 Can't bind to 'formGroup'

Tags: angular

I I have the following message:

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form

I imported the modules:

```
import { FormsModule,FormControl,FormBuilder,FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormControl,
    FormBuilder,
    FormGroup
  ],
```

New instance created:

```
      this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
...  
  }
```

In html:

```
  <form [formGroup]="addForm" novalidate class="form">
```

Comment: Where do you declare the component that you are using the `addForm` in? In `AppModule` or in a feature module? If it's in a feature module, you need to import the `ReactiveFormsModule` in that module.

Comment: Importing in feature module: import { FormArray,FormControl,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's no need to import `FormControl,FormBuilder,FormGroup` to the module.

So, try to import in the module only:

`import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

In the component where you initialize your form you just need import:

`import { FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: it does not work in   in app.module.ts 'import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';'    in module import { FormBuilder,FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

Comment: You need to that import of FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule to the Feature module, not an app.module.ts

Comment: not work - my Feature module import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormArray,FormControl,FormGroup,Validators } from '@angular/forms';

Comment: Well, okay
Is the component where you want to add form is declared in that feature module?